How do you reset Entra ID B2B passwords with the nativeclient endpoint?
Since Microsoft has broken MSAL with WinUI and doesn't appear to be interested in fixing it (the two versions of WebView2 do not want to coexist), I've been forced to implement the sign-on user-flow manually using the OAuth 2.0 protocols. I can construct an endpoint for the sign-in using the specifications:
https://tentant.b2clogin.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignIn_SignUp/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<clientId>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FentraId&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Ftenant.onmicrosoft.com%2Fapi%2Fread%20https%3A%2F%2Ftenant.onmicrosoft.com%2Fapi%2Fwrite

I now have a sign-in screen that works:

And, so far, so good. I can now log in using an embedded browser (WebView2).
The problem now is that the user's can't change their passwords. If you click on the 'Forgot your password' link, you get some cryptic nonsense that says:
error=access_denied&error_description=AADB2C90118:+The+user+has+forgotten+their+password.
Correlation+ID:+17e6877f-829a-40aa-9670-07bff9089f54
Timestamp:+2024-10-05+16:45:22Z

I imagine we're supposed to trap this in the callback and then force the conversation to a dialog that takes the user through a password reset. So, here's the question: Where is the endpoint for a password reset in Entra ID B2C?

Azure AD B2C users authenticated using user flow/custom policy do not support changing user passwords using graph api, you can only use password policies to change or reset user passwords.
